# Organizing site based on region and language

Tags: usability, website-design, language

I'm trying to come up with a way to organize the structure of a site but I'm at a loss on how to do it.

The site has content that based on region would either fall on US or Canada. Depending on the region, this content could also have an alternative language to it (French for Canada; Spanish for US).

What are ways to handle this and have the user be able to switch region/languages easily?

Comment: Do you just have US and Canada as regions, and English, French and Spanish as languages? Or are there other options as well for either?

Comment: The full list of region-language pairs are: US-EN, US-ES, CA-EN, CA-FR, MX-ES

Comment: Also, missed to ask if region and language have independent significances or are you asking the region just to determine the language?

Comment: There is significance. The US pages for example will include US-only information. Same goes with Canada and Mexico. So while the content may be similar there are slight differences.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any "clever" way to do this, so I would recommend using a very straightforward approach. I am sure I've seen this before, though I can't think of any websites to point you to.

On entry have the user select a country, followed by language choices for that country.

Once that initial preference is chosen, show them two separate actionable links or buttons:  Canada (Change) | English (Change)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking.

> What are ways to handle ***this*** and have the user be able to switch region/languages easily?

How to organize the structure logic? How to provide a translated version of the article(French to Spanish or Spanish to French), so it could be intuitive? Or how to program this correctly(I really, really hope you're not asking this kind of question)?

Anyway, I'll try to answer it shortly and perhaps after the clearing what exactly you're asking to enhance the answer accordingly.

The organizing structure logic should have parallel concept system for both languages. Then, you probably would want to connect each of equal content page to its translated version.

Providing intuitively understandable content is tricky and very often indeed depend on the local group of users(geographically or not). But in case of language, there's some worldwide standardize meanings, for example "globe" as an icon may represent a language.

If you asking about the programing, then you really shouldn't worry about it, as it's firstly not your problem to concern(as UX/UI designer), but if you do this by your own, then there's lots of best practices you probably would want to catch. For example, you may look for how google is doing it(not perfect) and enhance it wisely.